# How to pass value from one Adapter to another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-adapter

**ItemPriceAdapter class**

From this adapter class I want to pass the value using intent to another activity. I can't find problem in my code so please help me to figure out to send some value from this adapter class to another activity. Below is my code:

```
 holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (holder.like.isChecked()){

                int likecount = 0;
                likecount++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, ItemDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Likes", likecount+"");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

When I click on this like icon I want to increase number of likes and send those likes to another activity to show that how many likes are given for the item.

**ItemDetailActivity class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_detail);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    String like = getIntent().getStringExtra("Likes");
    Toast.makeText(this, like+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
    });
```

I am getting null value in my toast messsage.

Comment: `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();` after get value `String like = bundle .getString("Likes","");`

Comment: @HardikVasani not working. I already tried that but also tried once same as yours. Nop! You have any other ideas for that? I also tried using making String value static and tried to parse like MainActivity mna = new MainActivity(); and mna.methodname(); this also fails in my case. Please help me out !!

Comment: you can use this library for easy implementation https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 1):

You missing `startActivity(intent)` try this

```
 if (holder.like.isChecked()){

            int likecount = 0;
            likecount++;
            Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, ItemDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Likes", likecount+"");
            context.statrActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: considering he's in an adapter, he might need to use context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: @ZUNJAE I don't want to start that activity on clicking that icon. I want to pass the value using intent to that activity. Does using startActivity(intent) lets solve this problem?

Comment: When I use mcontext.startActivity(intent) it pass value without error but I don't want to call that activity. Is there another option>

Answer (score 0):

You have created an Intent, however you aren't starting it.

Make sure you call startActivity with that intent you created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Please Correct your code like this

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, ItemDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Likes", likecount+"");
            mcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

Then in onCreate() do this

```
String like = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Likes");
```

Comment: I don't want to open the activity on clicking that icon; all I wanna do is to pass value from that adapter class to another activity. I don't think your correction will help. As I know when I use startActivity(intent) it will open another activity. I don't want to do so, I want to pass the likes count value to that activity. Please re-comment me if you do have some solutions for my problem.

Comment: Sure I will do that

Comment: Use interface or broadcast receiver for that

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `context` in adapter to start an `Intent`

```
if (holder.like.isChecked()){

            int likecount = 0;
            likecount++;
            Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, ItemDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Likes", likecount+"");
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question but I think I have an answer to help you.

So since you don't want to `startActivity(intent)` in the even of the like button  `onClick(View v)`, you will have to either store the overall likes in sharedPreference or on a database and get it back `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` in your prefered activity. I recommend sharedPreference.